# Getting TypeError: Network request failed while using fetch in react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm getting `TypeError: Network request failed` when using fetch in react native.

Also when trying to navigate it does not seem to work. Maybe because I'm not reaching the code in the then block, due to the request failing.

Here is my code:

```js
const saveconsumer = (props) => {
  fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/consum",{
    method:"POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({
      "lenth": lenth,
      "width": width,
      "height":height
    })
  })
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(()=>{
    props.navigation.navigate("payment")
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
}
        
        
<Button 
  mode="contained"
  style={{margin:130,marginTop:18,marginBottom:1}}
  onPress={() => saveconsumer(props)}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: if you get rejected it go to catch so you should navigate in catch block

Comment: Where does the variables "lenth", "width" and "height" come from? 
Have you verified that the request works outside of react-native i.e. through postman or something similar?
The reason navigation is not working is probably because the request is failing and you are not reaching the "then" block, instead you reach the catch block. This is what happens when a promise fails.

Comment: "lenth", "width" and "height" comes from useState. I have verified that the request works outside of react-native

Comment: navigation is working in catch block but it takes about 1 min to navigate

Comment: @PrathameshJoshi are you running the react-native application on your local computer or on a device? Sounds like the request is timing out. Make sure the server is reachable from wherever you are running the react-native application.

Comment: I am running my application on emulator provided by android studio. In postman, there is no problem.